# Which encoding should I use for Cyrillic characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encoding, character-encoding

We store a Cyrillic text as blob data in our Oracle database. I want to read this blob data from the DB and show to users as text through the web browser but I don't know which encoding should I use or is there another way to do it correctly.

Currently, I am trying to convert blob data to string by using UTF8 but the screenshot is as below:

[image]

Could you please help on this issue?

Comment: Which method are you using to convert your blob data to UTF-8 ? Can you share it ?

Comment: Surely the question is which encoding was used for the data when it was put in?

Comment: @Jamiec is right, use the same encoding to get the `string` from the `byte[]` that you used before to get the `byte[]` from the `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read you must use exactly the same encoding that was used to store value to DB.

To output to a page you don't need to do anything special to get correct results in Utf8.